# XML to JSON - unexpected behaviour while converting lists?

Tags: java, json, xml

This is my json value:

```
{
    "hello": [
        {
            "names": {
                "name": "abc"
            }
        },
        {
            "names": {
                "name": "def"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using `XML.toString(new JsonObject())`, and this is what I get:

```
   <hello>
       <names>
          <name>abc</name>
       </names>
   </hello>
   <hello>
       <names>
          <name>def</name>
       </names>
   </hello>
```

Whereas, the xml I expected was this:

```
   <hello>
       <names>
          <name>abc</name>
       </names>
       <names>
          <name>def</name>
       </names>
   </hello>
```

This unexpected behaviour results in an invalid XML error, since there is no root element now. What am I missing here?

Comment: you mean `XML.toString(new JsonObject())`?

Comment: @Rehman: There is no other significant piece of code than just XML.toString(new JSONObject(string)).

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: Edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your JSON code. The `[]` means **array**, and by definition array is a *set* of elements. So the resulting xml code contains a *set* of `hello` elements. Try change your `[]` with `{}`:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "names": [
            {
                "name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "name": "def"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Just tried it and got the exact output you're looking for:

```
<hello>
    <names>
        <name>abc</name>
    </names>
    <names>
        <name>def</name>
    </names>
</hello>
```